# jQuery Split text() to get new lines

Tags: jquery, split

How to split the **.text()** , so that i should get new lines.

For suppose i have like this.

```
var loa = $('.loa_div').text();
alert(loa);
```

alert loa gives me,

```
Resultabc.resultdefgh.Resultkijklm.result12.Result888.kkkresult.123result.
```

I should get

```
Resultabc.    
resultdefgh.
Resultkijklm.
result12.
Result888.
kkkresult.
123result.
```

Comment: Do you use a character to separate your values, or do you use specific length?

Comment: its character.. i am not using length..

Comment: Infact my '.loa_div' is dynamic. The contents inside '.loa_div' changes everytime... And my issue is related to obtaining result in new line.  The link to duplicate doesnt related to my question.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. Not every line starts with Upper Case..  It might be like. 'Result123 result345 kkkresult'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str= "Resultabc.Resultdefgh.Resultkijklm.Result12.Result888";
var stresult=str.split('.').join('\n');
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dp49Y/2/

Comment: Thanks... but i forgot to mention . not every line has Upper case.. then how do i do it?

Comment: @user3778091, Please show some other string.

Comment: To be even more specific I have something like this 'MK1 --- 08-06-2014 --- schedule missingMK1 --- 09-06-2014 --- schedule missing'. which will be in a single line one after the other.

Comment: ok for suppose i have '.' at the end of every result character. is it possible to split and switch to new line exactly after '.' ??

Comment: @user3778091, I have updated my answer based on your feedback. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean split like below?

```
var loa = $('.loa_div').text();
alert(loa.split(/(?=Result)/).join("\n")); // use <br> instead if you want to display as html.
```